# A "simple" explanation of the concept of D-separation in a Bayesian Network?

Tags: bayesian-probability

Hello everyone.

I'm looking for a "simple" explanation of the concept of D-separation in a Bayesian Network.

As far as I know the **definition** is "two variables (nodes) in the network are D-Separated if the information is "blocked" between the two nodes by some evidence about the nodes in the middle.

But I can't pratically understand the concept.

I don't have enough rep to use images so these are the links to the images (just 25kbyte each one) from my dropbox folder.

Pattern 1: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60525806/Run_NoEvidence%28Sum%20Propagate%20Normal%29.JPG
Pattern 1: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60525806/Run_noEvidence%28Sum%20Propagate%20Normal%29%20_2.JPG
Pattern 3:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60525806/Run_NoEvidence%28Sum%20Propagate%20Normal%29%20_3.JPG

What I would like to understand if in these three patterns:

1. When there is **NO evidence** What (and why) nodes are D-separated from the each others
2. In what cases **EVIDENCE** about a specific node cause two nodes to be separated

Thank you in advance for any help.

Regards

Comment: The dropbox contents have expired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this tutorial http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/scheines/tutor/d-sep.html

Comment: thank you. I'll take a look later and of cource if it solves my doubts I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

I found the following tutorial better.
http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/d-sep.html

Comment: It's difficult to say whether this actually answers the question since the dropbox contents have expired.

Comment: it's a question back to 4 years ago. I don't even know where the original images are now :)

Comment: :p well, I was looking for a good d-separation tutorial for myself, and this question was one of the top search. Just wanted to make it convenient for someone else in my shoes. I read through multiple tutorials (including the answer you accepted), and the link I left was what really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to give you a simple way to think about the rules. Two nodes in a directed graph are dependent if, one is the ancestor of the other OR they both have a common ancestor.

Now observing a variable, changes the graph. All the ancestors of observed node, become descendants (descendants remain descendants), ie. information flows backwards. Now follow the same rules to find independence.

a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f (Graph before observation)
a <- b <- c <- d -> e -> f (Graph upon observing d)

Apply same rules on the graph to figure out independence.